# Is eating only fruits for breakfast healthy?

Tags: diet

I'm an athlete and trying to find what constitutes the healthiest breakfast I can eat. I'm considering wholemeal bread, bran flakes and fruits. So far fruits seem to be the tastiest option, but are they also the healthiest?

Comment: Any reason why you'd think it's not healthy and why you would go fruit-only? Adding more information helps us give better answers!

Comment: I have no idea! I just want to find out more.

Comment: Then have you tried finding more information? Like varying the types of fruit to get different kind of nutritions, references to diets who claim they've used it safely or articles that claim it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The food pyramid(s) are basically useless for practical numbers, but you can't fault the general advice: a balanced approach is generally best.

A real nutritionist would probably be required to give exact dietary figures, and it probably depends on what kind athletics you're doing.  But making sure you get enough protein (at breakfast and throughout the day) and complex carbs (especially early in the day) is probably a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like its a good start, but I'd also work in some protein.  Your body hasnt had any in hours, the whole time you've been sleeping.

Whey protein, eggs, cheese, a little bit of lean meat, etc.

Keep what you've mentioned so far tho, sounds like some good carbs for the morning.